# Can OWIN build a Claims Identity from multiple middlewares?

Tags: authentication, owin, claims-based-identity

In an app I'm building there are a few different authentication options. The first is mandatory, which is device authentication - this uses a proprietary authentication header with a device UID in it. The next tier of authentication is optional, which is JWT or API Key authentication; this uses a standard header (e.g. Bearer) and contains an appropriate token.

When a device authenticates, I build a claims identity with some claims containing things like the device UID. When a user authenticates, I build a claims identity with claims such as email, roles, etc.

A user will always be calling the service from an authorised device, so I would like the user's claims identity to contain the device UID claims. Is it possible to have OWIN build the claims identity from multiple sources?